# Can we use a regex with a common jquery query?

Tags: jquery

I would like to affect all my elements containing a class almost similar, i could iterate and use the iterator to do the job, but i am wondering if we could use a regex in this case:

```
$('.player').removeClass('player-1 player-2 player-3'); //player-n
```

Can the jQuery `removeClass` (and globaly the jquery methods which affects the DOM) treat a regex here ?

I am trying this:

```
$('.player').removeClass('/player-[0-9]+/');
```

The regex match i have tested it [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html), but it doesn't work on my DOM, does jQuery support the regex in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter like this

```
var elements = $('.player').filter(function() {
    return this.className = this.className.replace(/player-[0-9]+/, '');
});
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K7sbr/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use any css selector which are *kindof* a regex.

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

in your case it would be

`$("[class^='player-']")`

or

`$("[class|='player']")`